# Symfony2, Sonata : Remove an action from menu generated by a sonata bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I need to clean the admin side so it fits to the need of my client.

I'm using NewsBundle from Sonata, i actually don't need to use comments so i'd like to remove it from the admin side. At least from the menu. Is there a way to disable it in the config? I have not find any hints in the doc about this.

Here the specific area where i would like to not see it anymore :

[image: Sonata menu]

[image: Sonata menu]

By the way, the menu might be generated by KnpMenu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To customize the groups shown in the dashsboard and side menu, you need to edit your `app/config/config.yml`:

`sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        ...
        groups:
            sonata_blog:
                label: sonata_content
                label_catalogue: SonataNewsBundle
                icon: '<i class="fa fa-th"></i>'
                items:
                    # - sonata.news.admin.comment
                    - sonata.news.admin.post

            sonata.admin.group.classification:
                label:           sonata_classification
                label_catalogue: SonataClassificationBundle
                icon:            '<i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>'
                items:
                    - sonata.classification.admin.category
                    - sonata.classification.admin.tag
                    - sonata.classification.admin.collection
        ...`

Comment: That is perfectly working. But the rest is not generated automatically but that won't be a problem since that now, i have the solution to add it in the block ;). Thank you!

Comment: May i ask where do you get the admin pool names (Since i need to declare them now in the blocks)?

Comment: @Brieuc, you can use the symfony profiler (Container Parameters) or, depending of the sonata bundle, you can check it for example for news-bundle under `vendor/sonata-project/news-bundle/Resources/config/admin.xml` or for media-bundle `vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine_orm_admin.xml`...